# What is the React way of adding active class and removing others on hover in li elements

Tags: reactjs

This simple React component adds active class to every li element on hover event in pure javasript way. How can I achive adding active class on hover and removing other active classes from other li elements in React way? The similar I accomplish in 1 minutes simply adding this jquery lines on hover event:

```
$("li").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Nav extends Component {
    mouseEnter(e){
        e.target.classList.add('active')
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <ul>
                    <li key="1" onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)}><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li key="2" onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)}><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li key="3" onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)}><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li key="4" onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)}><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav
```

Updates:

As it is pure example, in some cases I need the menu to stay active so pure css is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `className` attribute and add `:hover` in your css file ?

Simple as this:

```
class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <ul>
                    <li key="1" className='item'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li key="2" className='item'><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li key="3" className='item'><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li key="4" className='item'><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

your css file

```
.item {
  ...some styles
}

.item:hover {
  ...some hover styles
}
```

or your sass file

```
.item {
  ...some styles

  &:hover {
    ...some hover style
  }

}
```

### One more note if you are using react router for your navigation:

if you using react-router for your navigation you have to use `NavLink` for your links inside your app which happes to has a `activeClassName` prop that serves the purpose you want:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string